# HashMap/ArrayList averaging program

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

A bit of a beginner with programming so do bear with me.

I've created an ArrayList inside a HashMap so that all my values can be added up to become a sum so that I can then divide the sum, by the number of entries to the ArrayList, which would give me my average... which is all working fine EXCEPT:

My first entry into my ArrayList is always coming back as 0.0 even when in the GUI I'm entering like 45 or whatever. How can I change it so that my ArrayList stops putting 0 on my first entry? As I've created an averaging program that would work if my first ArrayList entry was retrieving the correct entry, as oppose to the 0 it is bringing back everytime.

Here is my code:

```
public void addModRes( String mod, Integer res ) {

    ArrayList<Integer> nums = myMap.get(mod);
    if (nums == null) {
        nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    double sum = 0;
    double test =0;
    double avg =0;

    for (Integer number : nums) {
        sum += number;
    }
    //except sum is missing out the first entry in the ArrayList       
    System.out.println("The Sum of all the numbers in the array is " + sum);

    nums.add(res);
    myMap.put(mod, nums);

    test = nums.size();

    //System.out.println("This is the size of the array list "+ 
    numbers.size());

    avg = sum/test;

    System.out.println("this is the average: "+ average);
}
```

Comment: `avg = test/sum;` - you got it backwards. It should be `avg = sum/test;`

Comment: shouldn't it be `nums.add(res);` instead of  `numbers.add(res);`. Additionally, I don´t think you need `myMap.put(mod, nums);` since you are working on nums directly and it is already contained in myMap.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: In order to get real, well sounded answers, you have to enable us to reproduce what your code is doing. We can't because you are not showing us how that method is invoked and on what data it is operating.

Comment: I see that you include an `Integer res` to the function, I assume this is the integer to store the result to? In c++ this might be good practice but for an `Integer`, I think it's best to just let the function return the value you need instead of passing it a result variable.

Comment: Thank you Eran, I have now made that change. @GhostCat I've also edited my code I think it's more understandable now. I just need to know how to amend my ArrayList to take the first entry as oppose to it always being 0.. Not certain, but I don't think you need to see any more code than what is already there? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is about enabling us to reproduce the results you see. So: consider enabling us to **run** your code. Like: have a main method there - which could simply pass some example strings. Again: read [mcve]

Comment: I understand mate, apologies for my noobie-ness. :) problem solved now anyways thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you include the solution you found? For people that might run into the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your code and my guess is that you want something like this:

You want a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Interger>>` that stores lists of numbers (the `ArrayList<Integer>` from the `HashMap`) that can be identified with their `id` (the `String` in the `HashMap`).

1. Add a new list to the HashMap

Let's assume that we have an instance variable `listMap` in our class.

```
public int createList(String listId) {
    this.listMap.put(listId, new ArrayList<Integer>() );
    return this.listMap.size();
}
```

This will add a new `ArrayList<Integer>` to the `listMap`.

2. Add numbers to a certain list

We now write a new method to add numbers to a certain list

```
public int addNumberToList(String listId, Integer number) {
    this.listMap.get(listId).add(number);
    return this.listMap.get(listId).size();
}
```

3. Calculate the average for a certain list

Now we can use the lists to calculate their average

```
public double averageForList(String listId){
    double sum = 0;
    double average = 0;

    for (Integer number : this.listMap.get(listId) )
    {
         sum += number;
    }

    if (this.listMap.get(listId).size() != 0) average = sum / this.listMap.get(listId).size();

    return average;
}
```

And that should be it.

Comment: this is not what I was looking for but could be useful for the program in the future. I just want to find out why my ArrayList is always putting it's first entry as 0 no matter what I enter, which then means all my averages are coming back wrong. Apologies for not being more clear in my original question and thank you for your time.